# SVN error code - "70014" could not open the requested svn filesystem in windows

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to checkout my project using tortoise SVN but on opening repo-browser I get an error message :

```
 <D:error xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:m="http://apache.org/dav/xmlns" xmlns:C="svn:">
     <C:error/>
        <m:human-readable errcode="70014">Could not open the requested filesystem
       </m:human-readable>
 </D:error>
```

Can anybody help me to figure out what is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Please don't use multiple question marks. It count's as shouting on the internet, and shouting is not polite.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is problem on server (repository) side and indication of "Something went wrong, admin's intervention needed" - repository is in not clean state (or maybe even doesn't exist on such URL - it can be some misconfiguration)
2. From  server-side it will require at least `svnadmin verify` and, possible, `svnadmin recover` or even restoring repo from backup in worst case
3. Anyway, `svn co` in console give more readable error-message

**PS**: This question isn't for SO and can be on-topic only on SU or SF